# SonarLint Eclipse plugin - purpose of "Issue Locations" and "Rule Description" views

Tags: eclipse, code-analysis, static-code-analysis, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I just downloaded the SonarLint Eclipse plugin and successfully launched an analysis on my projet after configuring my SonarQube server.
The "SonarLint Report" and "SonarLint On-The-Fly" are correctly populated.
 However, the "SonarQube Issue Locations" and "SonarQube Rule Description" views remain empty.

Why that? What are they supposed to display? I didn't find an answer on the plugin's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initially open the *SonarQube Issue Locations* or *SonarQube Rule Description* Eclipse views on their own (for instance via *Quick Access*), they will appear empty as you have described in your answer.

Instead, you should navigate to the *SonarLint On-The-Fly* view, select an issue and right-click on it. Then select either *Rule description* or *Issue locations*, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Sonar Lint Rule description/Issue locations]

From that point onwards just selecting a different issue will automatically refresh the data in the *SonarQube Issue Locations* or*SonarQube Rule Description* views.

Comment: Thank you! I now understand the "SonarLint Rule Description" view and was able to check the rules of existing anomalies. However, when I check the "SonarLint Issue Locations" view, it always displays the message "No additional locations associated with this issue", even if the same issue occurs several times in the same file. How do you use it?

Comment: Only some issues will show up in that view. If the issue only concerns one location in your file, it will display "No additional locations associated with this issue". But for instance if you have 5 duplicated String literals (and have enabled that rule), it will show the five different locations within the file. ;-)